# Not getting proper frame by frame animation

Tags: android, animation

This is my code and resultpage1 and resultpage2 is my .jpg file.This is my background   image and i need this to be animated .The image is full of hearts and i need the hearts to fall down from top.Background image is added succesfully but animation is not proper.The hearts while falling are shaking rather falling down slowly.I need the hearts to fall down slowly instead shaking.Iam new to android.Please help

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/resultpage1"
    android:duration="50"/>
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/resultpage2"
    android:duration="50"/>
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/resultpage3"
    android:duration="50"/>
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/resultpage4"
    android:duration="50"/>
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/resultpage5"
    android:duration="50"/>
   </animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using optimized png images for this. You also are going to need more than two images in most cases. Your animation will almost have a strobe affect if you only use two images. Here is more information regarding different xml animations

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: But i have seen people using this jpg images for animation..!!I have used 5 images now but still the hearts are not falling slowly..Its shaky only  @Trent Pierce